# prevent reloading frameset after change location.hash in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.location

I have a frameset and want to change the window.location.hash of the frameset with js;

That works fine for IE and Firefox but the Chrome reloads the page;

I can't use pop and pushstate feature because i have to use the file Protocoll - > and so i run in the same origin policy.

Is there a chance to prevent the reloading of the frameset?

The Window.events unbeforeunload amd onhashchange didn't fire in Chrome when I change the hash in a frameset. Is there a other common way?

Thanks

Felix